# how to restore, update and save a trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code, i restore a trained model, named mymodel. and get tensor with name `'var_x'`. and then i change the value of `'var_x'` with concatenating a list [3]. at last, i save the new model.

if tf.assign sets variable name is `'var_x'`, the value in model newmodel still the same as value in model mymodel, without concatenating list [3].

if tf.assign sets variable name is `'var_y'` or others but not `'var_x'`, i can get correct value of `'var_y'` when restoring newmodel.

```
sess= tf.Session() # restore trained model--mymodel
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('mymodel.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(myfileDir, latest_filename = 
    'mymodel-checkpoint'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('var_x:0')
saver1 = tf.train.Saver()
x_update=tf.concat([x,[3]]) #change variable with concatenating list
y = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[4]), dtype = tf.float32)
tf.assign(y,x_update, name='var_x')
saver1.save(sess, 'newmodel', latest_filename='newmodel-checkpoint')
```

i don't know how to change my code to save the changed value with concatenating [3] in `'var_x'` in the model newmodel.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.assign` doesn't do the assignment immediately. Instead, it returns an assignment operation that you can evaluate with a `sess.run` call. Once you do that, your variable will have the value of `x_update`.

You can assign to `var_x:0` directly like this:

```
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('mymodel.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(myfileDir, latest_filename='mymodel-checkpoint'))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('var_x:0')
new_value = tf.concat([x, [3]], axis=0)
assign_op = tf.assign(x, new_value, validate_shape=False)
sess.run(assign_op)

saver1 = tf.train.Saver()
saver1.save(sess, 'newmodel', latest_filename='newmodel-checkpoint')
```

The key idea is that `x` refers to `var_x:0` which is already a `tf.Variable`. You need to use `validate_shape=False` on the assignment because you're changing the shape of `var_x`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the above statement can not assign value to the original variable 'var_x', but can assign value to  new variable. so even if i add sess.run, it can not assign value to 'var_x'

Comment: Updated my answer to explain how you can assign to `var_x`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have assigned to var_x according to your answer.